Does FFT filtering preserve the phase shift of a PSK signal?
I'm working with the wonderful Direwolf sound card TNC software, and am attempting to use the OpenCL clFFT GPGPU acceleration library to do FFT on the signal to replace the bandpass and lowpass filters with a much more efficient GPGPU accelerated FFT filter.
In PSK (phase key shifting) the signal waveform is shifted to encode information. This phase shift does not alter the frequency of the signal, and instead the identical frequency just has its waveform shifted.
If using FFT the frequency is the same in the frequency domain, and if we cancel out all other frequencies besides the desired frequency by multiplying them by zero, and then doing the inverse FFT, we should get a single, very powerful waveform.
So does this FFT and inverse FFT filter process destroy the phase shift information in the signal? If so what are some things we could do to preserve the phase key shift, such as using a specific sized filter or some other method?

"FFT filtering" is just filtering (if not buggy); it's the actual filter that defines the signal properties of that. In other words, it's the filter coefficients, and not the algorithmic shortcuts you take.
In communications we typically use linear-phase filters, since they have constant group delay and hence don't introduce any phase distortion.
So, if you use an appropriate filter design, and use a correct implementation of a convolution algorithm, then, there will be no problem with your PSK phase.

if we cancel out all other frequencies besides the desired frequency by multiplying them by zero

That, however, is not how you build a convolution algorithm. See this very popular answer to the question "Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?".
A note on computation: I'm all for accelerating of computations, but isn't TNC something with single- to two-digit kilohertz bandwidths and relatively large channel spacing? I don't really think anything computationally stronger than a toaster will benefit much from calculating the FFTs for these channels on a GPU (overhead of getting signal in and out of the GPU will outweigh the power saving compared to doing the same computations on a CPU); I'd expect that at these rates, a power-efficient method is actually to compute fast convolution ("FFT filtering") plain on the CPU. I might be wrong, and you need to have extremely steep frequency responses for some reason, but considering the age of everything involved, I'd be more than surprised if that was actually a way to get better signal out of it.

Just to add that even if we use linear phase filters we can introduce ISI - this is part of the “appropriate filter design” Marcus mentions! It’s not so simple, be sure to review the eye diagram before and after filtering to be sure this doesn’t get messed up (as it surely would if you just null bins in the FFT).

I'm planning on working with an electronics project of mine involving 1 mhz bandwidth signal (2 mhz ADC/DAC) to create an overpowered sound card. So with this increased bandwidth it may be necessary to GPGPU accelerate the digital signal processing and demodulation of the Direwolf software to keep up with the increased bandwidth.

@SteveMucci it really won't. 2 MHz is not a large sample rate at all, for modern machines at all: A 2014 computer could easily do significantly steeper filter than you would ever need at 160 (complex) Megasamples per second. At 1/160 of that rate of calculations, this is very well within in the realms of what a 5€ microcontroller can compute in software – in fact, that's what a lot of radio interface MCUs do.

You'd do that, anyways: before porting anything to the GPU (not everone has one that can run openCL anyways) you'd do a CPU software implementation of the same algorithm to have something to debug your GPU implementation. Feel absolutely free to use GNU Radio's FFT filters! They are GPL, just as Direwolf. (And GNU Radio has been used on bandwidths much larger than 1 MHz for two decades – purely on CPU :) You'll be fine without using your GPU, and as said, I suspect that for this workload, you actually burn more energy transferring data to and from the GPU than your CPU would consume computing)

Understood, thank you!
